# How to solve this error `ValueError: Value must be a list` in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, djongo

I have following code to update some records:

```
Product.objects.filter(id=4).update(feature={'top_selling':False})
```

When I try above code, got next error:

> ValueError: Value must be a list

Comment: `id=[4]` perchance?

Comment: If it is not what @IcedLance suggests, please post your model sample

Comment: i just add id=4 for  testing

Comment: feature=models.ArrayModelField(
       model_container=FeatureModel,
       model_form_class=FeatureModelForm
   )

Comment: can you show the product model

Comment: class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   feature=models.ArrayModelField(
       model_container=FeatureModel,
       model_form_class=FeatureModelForm
   )

Comment: class FeatureModel(models.Model):
    top_selling=models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    new_arrivals=models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    on_sale_product=models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    top_rated_product=models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

Comment: did you try `Product.objects.filter(id=4).update(feature=[{'top_selling':False}])`?

Comment: while try that method it show ValueError: Array items must be Model instances @Vishal.R

Comment: Try selecting from the feature table and updating here. Something like, `Product.objects.filter(id=4).update(feature=Feature.objects.get(top_selling=False))`

Comment: when i try that method AttributeError: type object 'FeatureModel' has no attribute 'objects' @Vishal.R

Comment: Weird. Maybe there is an inbuilt object FeatureModel that overrides this. Did you try importing it with a different name like `from models import FeatureModel as somename` and try `Product.objects.filter(id=4).update(feature=somename.objects.get(top_selling=False))`

Answer (score 0):

`filter(id=4)` is absolutely fine.

I see from your comments that the field `feature` on the Product model is a `ArrayModelField` (I presume it's from [this package](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/array-model-field/)?), which looks like it accepts a list of models.

You're currently trying to assign the dictionary `{'top_selling':False}` as the value for this field, when it should be something like `[feature_instance_1, feature_instance_2]`, or something similar.

Does that make sense?

What are you trying to do? Is `top_selling` a field on `Feature`?

Comment: i couldn't understand @Tom Hamilton Stubber

Answer (score -2):

You should try

```
Product.objects.filter(id=4).update(feature=[{'top_selling':False}])
```

Or make a id as list.

```
Product.objects.filter(id=[4]).update(feature={'top_selling':False})
```

Comment: get().update() - is not supported in querysets - it wont work